# Output happening twice during while loop(Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a couple of tests for a school project. Every time I run it the output gets outputted twice, there are no hints as to why but I've tried everything that I can.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = sc.next();
    int x = 5;
    int y = 500;

    while(x>=0){
        System.out.println("You have "+x+" x left.");
        System.out.println("menu\nnext");
        String answer = sc.next();    

        switch (answer){
            case "menu":
                System.out.println("Your name is "+name+".");
                System.out.println(y);
                continue;

            case "next":
                x = (x-1);
                System.out.println (x);
                break;
        }   
    }  
}
```

Output when you select menu comes out to

Your name is (name)
500
menu
next
Your name is (name)
500
menu
next

Comment: by output, do you mean every single one of these print statements appears to execute twice? or just some of them?

Comment: Please show a sample session, with input and output. Highlight the part which is twice and should be once.

Comment: also just as an aside, it's a little confusing for you to prompt with "What is your name" when it seems like you want them to select either the "menu" or "next" option. You might want to separately have them input their name and then the option they want

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what is printed twice? your code seems fine, you only need to work on the presentation.
However, if you want to loop 5 times for example, change the loop condition to x!=0 or x>0. Because in your case the loop is executed 6 times instead of 5.

And good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your name?");
String name = sc.next();
int x = 5;
int y = 500;

while(x>=0){
    System.out.println("You have "+x+" x left.");
    System.out.println("menu\nnext");
    String answer = sc.next();    

    switch (answer){
        case "menu":
            x = (x-1);
            System.out.println("Your name is "+name+".");
            System.out.println(y);
            continue;

        case "next":
            x = (x-1);
            System.out.println (x);
            break;
    }   
}  
}
```